# How to find clients for my start-up?

Tags: start-up

I will launch a start-up with a couple of friends. We will work as data science and data engineering consultancy. All of us have similar backgrounds in maths, physics, and electrical engineering. How to find clients?
 How to build a network? I have some personal contacts, but that is not enough.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about personal finance.

Comment: I'm wondering if this may be a better fit on workplace, or on a forum dedicated to startups or marketing.

Comment: Look up Gary Vee.

Comment: What is the product of your start-up and who is a potential customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - build media presence.
You should probably start with building a website in which you describe what you do, why you are good at it and why should the client choose you over your competitors. You have to build an online presence(FB,IG etc..).The site and all your profiles should be optimized.
You will need good SEO in order to get those clients to your site and all the digital marketing tools to track your progress.

Comment: Can you tell open-source digital marketing tools?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really now which are open-source, but the mainstream ones do the job quite well

Comment: Which are the mainstream ones?

Comment: Google Trends, Ahrefs, Facebook Audience Insights, Facebook Ads, Google Adwords, Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager, Facebook Analytics, Google Keyword Planner